# SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SDK?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Where is the [SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx) [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516)?

---

### Bonus Reading

In order to create a database in *SQL Server Compact Edition* you must call the function `ME_CreateDatabase` exported from `sqlceme40.dll`:

[image]

The function is [not documented on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=ME_CreateDatabase&x=0&y=0), and [the header files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516) do not ship with [the redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) (obviously).

MSDN mentions 3 *Compact Edition* header files:

- **`sqlce_err.h`**: Error codes used by database
- **`sqlce_oledb.h`**: OLEDB standard programming interfaces
- **`sqlce_sync.h`**

That page also mentions that, [*if i had the SDK*, the header files would be located in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516):

> SQL Server Compact 4.0 header files are installed under %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Include.

But i don't, so they aren't:

[image]

So where ***is*** the *SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 SDK*?

---

**Bonus Chatter**

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174579.aspx)

> ### Building an OLE DB Application (SQL Server Compact)
>
> The next step in building an OLE DB-enabled application is to include the appropriate header files. In the main entry point for your application, add include statements for the SQL Server Compact OLE DB provider and the SQL Server Compact error file:
>
> ```
> #include <sqlce_oledb.h>
> #include <sqlce_err.h  >
> ```

Comment: It seems to me that if `ME_CreateDatabase` is undocumented, it's probably designed to be called internally by the database engine. Am I missing something here? There are literally thousands of internal functions called by SQL Server CE 3.5 that aren't documented (because they're **internal**). Also, you provide a link in your opening paragraph that mentions nothing about the SDK being available. Where do you see that it is?

Comment: @KenWhite i added a 2nd link to [the MSDN page that mentions the *existance* of the 4.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174516). Strictly speaking it looks like SSCE does something similar to GDI+: there is a flat API, but Microsoft provides header files that contain C++ code to wrap the flat API into classes. Since i'm using another native programming language, i'll be needing to translate the C/C++ header files into pascal.

Comment: This [MSDN forum page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d418401c-a4a4-454a-a11e-cfafb6a3cf7d) mentions installing VS 2010 SP1 + the SQL Server Compact 4.0 Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Tools.

Comment: OK. I'm still a little lost, though. According to a link from the *very page* in your last comment, there's a `CreateDatabase` method that's used to "create a database" (so the `ME_CreateDatabase` is not needed after all). I see @JohnDewey solved the problem of the missing SDK headers, though. :) Maybe you could edit your question to remove all the extraneous noise and just ask about where to find the SQL Server CE 4.0 SDK?

Comment: @KenWhite i presume you mean [this `CreateDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173396) method. Unfortunately that is not an API i can call. The reason i cannot call it is because it does not exist as an API.

Comment: Still lost. <g> With no SDK, how do you know it doesn't exist as an API? It seemss (from your own links) that it's there. I still think you could reduce this question to "I can't find the SQL Server CE 4.0 SDK. Can anyone point me to a link?". The images are pretty, but don't appear to be relevant, and the majority of the text is describing the images. (The pic of a function that probably is internal doesn't help anything, and text listing the .h files and the fact that you don't have an `include` folder in the `SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0` tree which contains them would probably suffice.)

Comment: i've found the 3.0 SDK. Someone at Microsoft wrapped the "native" `ME_xxx` dll function calls into a C++ class. That C++ class is what you'll find in the header files. If you want do native Compact Edition development with another development tool (e.g. Delphi, C, Assembly Language) you will have to re-create the class wrapper around the dll exports in your own language (or call the dll exports directly if your language doesn't have classes). Either way i still need `v4.0` of the Compact Edition SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The files are included in the package SSCE 4.0 Design Tools (SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi) ([documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341(v=vs.110).aspx)). This executable is available on the Visual Studio 2012 Premium Edition DVD. Possibly in other editions and verisons as well, but this is the only one I have.

I needed the files myself and after digging around for an hour I found it there.

Answer (score 0):

As Nitramk posted, I found SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi on the VS 2012 iso's in packages\ssce40. It's also included in the 2012 Ultimate trial (and probably Pro). As of now, the trials are still available from MS. Search for "visual studio 2012 ultimate trial" or "visual studio 2012 trial".

Note that I don't see them in VS 2013 or 2015.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the 'Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3' link on the blog page and install that.
Then you'll get the header files & samples installed into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0

Comment: I tried both the installer ways from [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) and the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2) links as in the blog and none of them are deploying the `include` folder.