# I don't have SqlServerCe assembly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a simple WinForms app that uses an .sdf database to store data.  I saw [this](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql-revisited/) interesting post on how to handle multithreaded access, which seemed useful.  Problem is, I can't find the System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly.  I installed the Sql Server Compact 3.5 SDK, but that reference still doesn't show up in my .NET assemblies list when I go to add the reference.  What am I missing?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7.

Comment: What version of VS are you running? it will not work with the express editions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to "Tools" and select "Choose Toolbox Items..." and select .Net Framework components and see if any of the SqlServerCe components shows up, then select one of the System.Data.SqlServerCe components, if you then add it to your form it will add the reference to your project.

[image]

Comment: For myself, I can only seem to see SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlCommandBuilder - so no SqlCe... items. Is there any define with my items not being SqlCe... ? thanks

Comment: @Samuroid did you install the [SQL Server Compact SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10070)?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747518/sql-server-compact-edition-4-0-sdk

Comment: @MarkHall Yes I believe I have. I have the Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition directory under ProgramFiles

Comment: @Samuroid you will need to click the browse button and go to the directory and select the proper dll per compentent_tech's answer

Comment: @MarkHall thanks, I managed to get it working now :) However upon trying to access the data in my tables I get this error message, "Database file may be corrupt..."

Comment: You probably should ask that as a question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to browse to the assembly in order to get it included.

Comment: Where is it?  I looked in the SDK folder and the closest thing is System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll.  MSDN says it should be System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: On my system, it is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Private

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this post on MSDN : [How to find correct "System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll" in desktop project?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/29419846-df47-4a45-b8b3-6aeb9ed6d9db)

Comment: I've done all this.  And I should note that I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my database as a Data Source solved the problem for me.
(Shift + Alt + D) then Add New Data Source knowing that my .sdf database is already connected with my project via Data Explorer.