# SqlServerCe does not exist in dll list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, sql-server-ce

I tried to add `System.Data.SqlServerCe` reference to my `winform` project but it doesnot exist in my DLL list.

I tried this questions but does not work:

[I don't have SqlServerCe assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714480/i-dont-have-sqlserverce-assembly)

[Cannot find namespace 'System.Data.SqlServerCe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493674/cannot-find-namespace-system-data-sqlserverce)

I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install first on your computer:

*Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2:* http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783

or

*Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0 SP1*: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

After install add reference by option Browse (in my case this assembly is in the directory: *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop*):

[image]